# Losing rows on Google BigQuery after doing a WHERE / through unnesting/flattening

Tags: sql, nested, google-bigquery

I got daily tables from Google Analytics about a website. In the table are 167.286 rows. The main target is to create a new table (CSV) with only the needed columns and rows. Using Legacy SQL I have this query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS string), CAST(fullVisitorId AS string), CAST(visitNumber AS string), CAST(hits.hitNumber AS string)) AS identifier,
  hits.hitNumber as hitNumber,
  hits.page.pagePath as pagePath,
  hits.page.pagePathLevel1 as pagePathLevel1,
  hits.page.pagePathLevel2 as pagePathLevel2,
  hits.appInfo.exitScreenName as exitScreenName,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory as eventCategory,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction as eventAction,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel as eventLabel,
  hits.customDimensions.value as value,
  hits.customDimensions.index as index,
  visitId,
  fullVisitorId,
  date,
  visitNumber,
  totals.hits as hits,
  totals.pageviews as pageviews,
  device.deviceCategory as deviceCategory,
  geoNetwork.city,
  channelGrouping,
  trafficSource.campaign as campaign,
  trafficSource.source as source,
  trafficSource.medium as medium
FROM
  [project:dataset.table]
WHERE NOT hits.customDimensions.value = "PrivateUser" AND NOT hits.customDimensions.value = "LoggedIn"
```

At the first moment I am using a WHERE statement I am losing rows which should not be effected by the WHERE statement.

After this I got a total number of 77.250 rows.  But each of the excluded values has 23.825 rows. I get the 23.825 rows when I modify the WHERE statement to `WHERE hits.customDimensions.value = "PrivateUser"`. The same goes for "LoggedIn".

167.286 - 2*23.825 = 119.636 and not 77.250. So I am losing 42.386 rows and I don´t have a clue why.
Has anybody an idea why this is happening? I just want to have all the rows except the rows where value is not PrivateUser and LoggedIn. And that should be more than 77.250.

This problem appears in Legacy and Standard SQL. This is the same query but in Standard SQL:

```
SELECT
    columns (modified like the unnesting statement)
FROM 
    `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as c 
WHERE
    NOT c.value = "PrivateUser" AND NOT c.value = "LoggedIn"
```

I am losing 42.386 rows again and dont kow why :(

I think I am coming more near to the cause of this problem: The nested schema.

If I doing the Standard SQL query without the WHERE statement I get a total number of 124.900 rows. So here are 42.386 rows missing again.
It seems that the reason for this is the unnesting or flattening of the data.

**Maybe a better question is "How can I unnesting or flattening my data without a loss of my data?".**

If I click on the button "Hide Options". selecting an output table and and activating "Allow Large Results" and "Flatten Results" I get the error message "Cannot FLATTEN non-repeated field hits_1" f.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery's legacy SQL dialect can have confusing semantics in relation to `COUNT(*)`, assuming that that is what you are using. If you use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead, the results will likely be as expected. Your query might be something like:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `your-dataset.your-table`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(customDimensions)
  WHERE value IN ('PrivateUser', 'LoggedIn')
);
```

Alternatively, if you are trying to count the number of `customDimensions` elements where `value` is not one of those strings, you can do:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UNNEST(customDimensions)
       WHERE value NOT IN ('PrivateUser', 'LoggedIn'))) AS value_count
FROM `your-dataset.your-table`;
```

You can read more about the differences between legacy and standard SQL in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: I am not using COUNT, I am just using SELECT and then the columns I like to have. And unfortunately I have the same problem with Standard SQL. This is the same query but in Standard SQL and not legacy: `SELECT columns FROM ..., UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as c WHERE NOT c.value = "PrivateUser" AND NOT c.value = "LoggedIn"` I am losing 42.386 rows again and dont kow why :(

Comment: It doesn't look like you are running the query that I suggested if you are using a cross join with `hits` and `customDimensions`. Can you maybe update your question with a better description of your query?

Comment: Of course. I updated the question/problem and hopefully it is more understandable.

Comment: Referring to the query in your updated question, it could also be the case that there are some `c.value` that are `NULL`, in which case they will be excluded. You could try expressing the filter as `(NOT c.value = "PrivateUser" AND NOT c.value = "LoggedIn") OR c.value IS NULL`.

Comment: That OR statement is fixing my problem and avoids the lost of the rows. Thank you so much for this hint!

Answer (score 2):

> **Maybe a better question is "How can I unnesting or flattening my data without a loss of my data?".**

This issue has nothing to do with `unnesting` or `flattening` your data
Rather it is just how [WHERE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#where-clause) clause works:

> The WHERE clause filters out rows by evaluating each row against bool_expression, and discards all rows that do not return TRUE (that is, rows that return FALSE or NULL).

So, in your case those rows where c.value IS NULL - they are being excluded because for such rows your WHERE clause returns `NULL`, thus being filtered out

You can see this with below simplified example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT NULL AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' )
SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT value = 'a'
```

the result is

```sql
value   
----- 
b
```

As you can see rows with 'a' and NULL are being filtered out

So, as Elliott suggested, you should explicitly state that you want to keep NULLs in your result, as in below (for example)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT NULL AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' )
SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT value = 'a' OR value IS NULL
```

As expected, now result is:

```sql
value    
-----
b    
null
```

As an option (depends on coding preferences) you can do as below

```sql
SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT IFNULL(value, '') = 'a'
```

If, as it is in your example, you want to exclude multiple values - repeating of `IFNULL(value, '')` for each is not what you want so you can use below approach

```sql
SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT IFNULL(value, '') IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, this helped for a better understanding!